# xamarin build could not load clrcompression.dll

Tags: xamarin, build, uwp

Hy,
I'm developing an UWP application in xamarin pcl. But when I want to build the application in release mode it gives an error that doesn't show in debug mode.

When I go back to debug mode and enable the debug setting "Common language runtime exceptions" I get the following error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'clrcompression, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.
  Source=
  StackTrace:
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

But the dll is located in the release and in the debug folders.

How to fix?

UPDATE:
details:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'clrcompression, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

Comment: The `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`  occurs when the file is not found or miss assembly.Please try to  get place where the exception throw via [`Manage exceptions with the debugger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger). Let me know the result.

Comment: Nico Zhu, The exception throws in the init of the application by :"Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assemblies);"

Comment: And the assemblies are the custom renderers and effects from class libs.